# How to make checkboxes on row checked/unchecked with values 1/0 from database?

Tags: php, ajax

I have problems with my code. I have table filled with SQL data. I want to make my checkboxes checked if Barva = 1 and unchecked if Barva = 0.

I tried to add this code `<?php if ($row['status'] == 1) { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>` between `<td contenteditable="false"><form method="post"><input type="checkbox"  name = checkbox'.$row[ID].'></form></td>` but I failed with syntax.

Can someone help me please?

[Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzUbG.png) -this is how it looks like

[SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KniC.png) - sql view

```
$output = '
<br />
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
 <tr>
  <th width="1%">!</th>
  <th width="1%">ID</th>
  <th width="10%">Inventární číslo</th>
  <th width="10%">Serial Number</th>
  <th width="10%">Produkt</th>
  <th width="10%">Oddělení</th>
  <th width="10%">Místnost</th>
  <th width="10%">IP</th>
  <th width="10%">Síť/USB</th>
  <th width="10%">Datum</th>
  <th width="10%">Funkce</th>
 </tr>
';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $page->checkbox_state = $row["Barva"];  
 $output .= '
 <tr>
  <td contenteditable="false"><form method="post"><input type="checkbox" 
  name = checkbox'.$row[ID].'></form></td>
  <td contenteditable="true">'.$row["ID"].'</td>
  <td contenteditable="true">'.$row["Inventárníčíslo"].'</td>
  <td contenteditable="true" class="jmeno">'.$row["SerialNumber"].'</td>
  <td contenteditable="true">'.$row["Produkt"].'</td>
  <td contenteditable="true">'.$row["Oddělení"].'</td>
  <td contenteditable="true" class="jmeno">'.$row["Místnost"].'</td>
  <td contenteditable="true">'.$row["IP"].'</td>
  <td contenteditable="true">'.$row["USB"].'</td>
  <td contenteditable="true">'.$row["Datum"].'</td>
 </tr>
 ';
}

$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Where exactly did you put that check?

Comment: <input type="checkbox"  name = checkbox'.$row[ID].' ...here ...></form></td>

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, hard to read etc. Instead, please [edit] your question and paste the complete code with your check there. Note: it's always a good idea to enclose your attribute values in quotes, your `name` attribute currently has no quotes, which might be the reason your check doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I think you can use like  below to get checkbox checked:



 $output = '
    <br />
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <tr>
      <th width="1%">!</th>
      <th width="1%">ID</th>
      <th width="10%">Inventární číslo</th>
      <th width="10%">Serial Number</th>
      <th width="10%">Produkt</th>
      <th width="10%">Oddělení</th>
      <th width="10%">Místnost</th>
      <th width="10%">IP</th>
      <th width="10%">Síť/USB</th>
      <th width="10%">Datum</th>
      <th width="10%">Funkce</th>
     </tr>
    ';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $page->checkbox_state = $row["Barva"];  
     $isChecked="";
     if($row["Barva"]==1)
     {
      $isChecked="checked='checked'";
     }
     $output .= '
     <tr>
      <td contenteditable="false"><form method="post"><input type="checkbox" 
      name = checkbox'.$row["ID"].' '.$isChecked.'></form></td>
      <td contenteditable="true">'.$row["ID"].'</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">'.$row["Inventárníčíslo"].'</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="jmeno">'.$row["SerialNumber"].'</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">'.$row["Produkt"].'</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">'.$row["Oddělení"].'</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="jmeno">'.$row["Místnost"].'</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">'.$row["IP"].'</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">'.$row["USB"].'</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">'.$row["Datum"].'</td>
     </tr>
     ';
    }
```